# Verify that the eigenvector is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I saw similar questions on the forum, but I still have some doubts. I use a more general form of symbol matrix *A* to verify that the eigenvector is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalues. The code is as follows:

```
A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[A];
A // MatrixForm
Transpose[vecs] // MatrixForm
DiagonalMatrix[vals] // MatrixForm
A . Transpose[vecs] === Transpose[vecs] . DiagonalMatrix[vals]
```

Running results：

[image]

I checked the code operation logic and there was no problem, but the result was **False**. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 5):

`===` looks for exact structural match, Not mathematical equivalence. and since terms on both sides are formatted different, it will not work. You can use Simplify or Reduce.

```
Simplify[A . Transpose[vecs] - Transpose[vecs] . DiagonalMatrix[vals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[ A . Transpose[vecs] == Transpose[vecs] . DiagonalMatrix[vals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Reduce[A . Transpose[vecs] == Transpose[vecs] . DiagonalMatrix[vals] ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have found the reason, thanks.

Comment: Simplify[
 A . Transpose[vecs] == Transpose[vecs] . DiagonalMatrix[vals]]